# compare fields from previous document mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have inserted log data from a server in a mongodb collection. Using aggregate functions the log data has been reduced to the following document structure:

```
{ "connectionCount" : "576", "eventTime" : "2016-08-16T12:33:58.536" }
{ "connectionCount" : "588", "eventTime" : "2016-08-16T12:34:58.549" }
{ "connectionCount" : "590", "eventTime" : "2016-08-16T12:35:58.558" }
{ "connectionCount" : "594", "eventTime" : "2016-08-16T12:36:58.572" }
{ "connectionCount" : "595", "eventTime" : "2016-08-16T12:37:58.587" }
{ "connectionCount" : "596", "eventTime" : "2016-08-16T12:38:58.597" }
{ "connectionCount" : "599", "eventTime" : "2016-08-16T12:40:58.618" }
{ "connectionCount" : "602", "eventTime" : "2016-08-16T12:43:58.648" }
{ "connectionCount" : "604", "eventTime" : "2016-08-16T12:45:58.698" }
{ "connectionCount" : "606", "eventTime" : "2016-08-16T12:46:58.708" }
{ "connectionCount" : "607", "eventTime" : "2016-08-16T12:48:58.728" }
{ "connectionCount" : "609", "eventTime" : "2016-08-16T12:50:58.754" }
```

I want to identify the eventTime when the connectionCount increased by more than 10 from the preceding eventTime, considering that the collection documents are sorted on eventTime. How can this be achieved in mongodb

Comment: I guess the reason you are asking is because you store `connectionCount` as string. Am I right?

Comment: I can convert connectionCount to integer. Do you have a solution if connectionCount is integer.